# Notification based on data from JSON - Android Studio

Tags: android, json, notifications

I'm developing Android Application. I'm downloading data in JSON using Volley. Now I would like to do something like this: application, even when closed is downloading data once in 5 minutes, then checking and if some value is above certain level then it's sending notification to the user. I'm sure that there is plenty about it in internet, but I'm not sure where and about what should I search? Services?

Regards,

Comment: Search services with countdowntimer.

Comment: U need an alarm manager that will trigger an IntentService. Thats it !

Comment: I have similar problem. I use `AlarmManager` triggering `IntentService` but approximately 2 hours it stop working. I tested on `Android 8.0 Oreo`. I know that new APIs has more restrictions. But how can I solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to schedule regular data download you should use AlarmManager:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
you can find info about notifications.